# How to return a string that has a special character - BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm very new to SQL, and I've been practicing on a dataset, but I seem to have run into some trouble:

I want to pull a certain coffee processing method: "Natural/Dry". But when I go to run my query, BigQuery just tells me that "there's no data to display."

This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT Processing_Method, Acidity, Total_Cup_Points
  FROM DF
  WHERE Processing_Method='Natural/Dry'
```

I know the "/" is part of the issue, but I'm not sure what to do to solve it. What would the solution be?

Thanks!!

Comment: `WHERE lower(Processing_Method) like 'natural%dry'`

Comment: That's unexpected. Please share the DDL for your table.

Comment: I believe @Samuel was on the right track. If you do not care about the capitalization of your "Processing_Method" than you could use following. `WHERE lower(Processing_Method) = 'natural/dry'` This will ensure that any exact string 'natural/dry' no mater the capitalization would show up in your results. 

Also check you column types on the tables if you are using a fixed char col type you may need to pad the string at the end with spaces to make the size of the string the same as the col. Or you could change the where to the following `WHERE lower(Processing_Method) like 'natural/dry%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to run the query without running into any issues. Test code I ran in BigQuery below. Perhaps there aren't any Processing_Method equal to 'Natural/Dry.' You can try a wildcard search and use NORMALIZE_AND_CASEFOLD(Processing_Method) like in example 2.

```
WITH
  a AS (
  SELECT
    'Natural/Dry' AS Processing_Method
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Test')
SELECT
  *
FROM
  a
WHERE
  Processing_Method='Natural/Dry'
```

---

```
WITH
  a AS (
  SELECT
    'Natural/Dry' AS Processing_Method
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Test')
SELECT
  *
FROM
  a
WHERE
  NORMALIZE_AND_CASEFOLD(Processing_Method) like '%natural%dry%'
```